# конструктор копирования - присвоить дочерний класс родительскому

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, конструктор, полиморфизм

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Player();
        Player(&Player) const;

    private:
        Item * item;
}

class Item
{
    public:
        Item();
        void virtual Use();
}

class Sword : public Item
{
    public:
        Sword();
        void virtual Use();
}

Player::Player()
{
    item = new Sword();
}

Player::Player(&Player p)
{
    item = new Item(*(p.item));
}
```

У игрока есть поле типа "указатель на предмет", куда обычно присваиваются указатели на объекты производных от "предмета" классов - к примеру, "меч".
Мне необходимо скопировать игрока, после чего вызвать метод Use() того предмета, который сохранён в поле. После долгого сидения в отладчике возникло ощущение, что у копии игрока при вызове item->Use() вызывается метод родительского класса (пустой).

Comment: Для начала, добейтесь чтобы Ваш код компилировался. А хорошо бы и вовсе видеть [mcve].

Comment: Перенес в коммент: почему у Вас конструктор копирования идет с ```const``` ? Как у Вас получится что-либо скопировать, если Вы сами запрещаете изменять объект ?

Comment: 1) Код в оригинале многократно больше, тут специально упростил - он нужен только для демонстрации вопроса, т.е. и ответ ожидался не в виде рабочего кода. 2) Конструктор копирования const, потому что оригинальный объект не меняется. По крайней мере, так написано в учебнике, который лежит у меня на полке. И надо признать, проблем с ними я не испытывал никогда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку на самом деле при копировании вам надо сохранить конечный тип предмета, применить `new Item(...)` невозможно ни с каким аргументом.
Для создания копии предмета надо точно знать его конечный тип. 
Можно применить паттерн "виртуальный конструктор" aka клонирование:

```
class Item
{
    public:
        Item();
        virtual void Use();
        virtual Item* Clone() const =0;
        virtual ~Item() {}
}

class Sword : public Item
{
    public:
        Sword();
        void Use();
        Item* Clone() const { return new Sword (*this); }
}

Player::Player(const Player& p)
{
    item = p.item->Clone();
}
```

Comment: Еще виртуальный деструктор в `Item` добавить следует.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, то что нужно! Виртуальный деструктор в оригинальном коде есть, пример писал из головы и решил что для демонстрации вопроса можно обойтись без него.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте для верности специальный конструктор, который будет вызывать унаследованный, а потом копировать поля класса. И вызывайте при копировании его.
Сейчас вы просто создаете еще один пустой объект типа Player.